# remove page title using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I am developing a chat functionality. When two persons are chatting the page title of the one who receives the message will indicate that you received a message from...

```
var titles = []
var text = "you received a message from... "
titles.push(text);
```

Once the message is read the text is removed from the title(Same as facebook chats). 
I remove the text from title by

```
function remove(){
titles.splice(i,1)
}
```

The prob is if the site is opened in more than one tab or opened in more than one window I am not able to remove the page title from all the opened tabs and windows if the chat message is read.

Comment: `document.title` will work for you

Comment: @Sahal `document.title` will only work for the window that it's called in.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question, you can try this;

```
<title>original title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTitle(title) { document.title = title; }
</script>
<input type='button' onclick='changeTitle("new title")' value='Change Title'/>
```

Comment: This will change the title of one tab only. But I need to change the title of all the opened tabs.

Answer (score 0):

`document.title` will work for you

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_title.asp

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` to run updates. You could use `titles.shift()` to get the first title in array and remove it from array

```
setInterval(function(){
   /* make sure titles array isn't empty first*/
   if( titles.length){
       document.title=titles.shift();
   }
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// on the return of the ajax function if there is a new message add this
    $(this).attr("title", "you received a message from");

});
</script>
```